# Cancelling a Task, using multiple CancellationSourceTokens

Tags: c#, task, token, cancellation

I have a 'Start' button that creates a new token source and a 'Stop' button that Cancels the token source.

I have the cancellation token source defined outside my functions within the class:

```
public static CancellationTokenSource cts;
```

When you click the start button I have the following task set to run 10 seconds from when started:

```
cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith((x) => PostGoingReport(cts));
```

Inside the method I am checking to ensure the token has not been cancelled before running:

```
if (cts.IsCancellationRequested )
{
    return;
}
```

And in the stop button I have:

```
cts.Cancel();
```

When you click the start button, then click the stop button it works as expected and doesn't post the report.

However, if you click the start button, then stop, and then the start button again the Task runs twice. 
This is because I am creating the same instance of the CancellationTokenSource so the token source isn't requested for cancellation anymore.

Is there a way I can make it so the task is linked to THAT specific tokensource?

The reason I am asking this is because my app 'Sleeps' and cancels all tasks between certain hours and then wakes up, and it seems to wake up and post the report twice instead of once.

Comment: *Don't* use a global variable to hold the CTS. Don't let the delay get lost either. The way this code is written you may get exceptions 10 seconds after you close the form. If you want to keep track of multiple tasks and CTSs, put them in a container, eg list or queue. You'll have to decide *what* that button cancels too. Oldest task? Newest task?

Comment: You haven't told either `Task.Delay` nor `ContinueWith` that there is a `CancellationToken` involved, and your delegate means that there will be a delayed execution of `PostGoingReport(cts)` which means it will capture whatever `cts` is active when it executes. If you start, then stop, then start, your code will use the second token, and not the first.

Comment: In short, don't use a global token variable, capture the current `CancellationToken` in your Start method and pass that to `Task.Delay`, `Task.ContinueWith` as well as your method (which should not take a `CancellationTokenSource` but a `CancellationToken`)

Comment: I need the cts as a global variable as I am using it in other areas, such as the  stop button, if its local i can't use it or pass it into the stop button.

Comment: Just noticed I have been using: await Function(cts) then checking the token inside the function instead of Task.Run(Function(),ct.Token) stupid me.

Comment: You should pass the token to the function as well, unless you mean that once the function has started it is too late to cancel it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rewrite your code somewhat:

1. Restructure your method to take a `CancellationToken` instead of a `CancellationTokenSource`.
2. Pass this token to `Task.Delay`, `Task.ContinueWith` as well as your `PostGoingReport` method (which thus needs to take the token, and not the source)
3. The start method should construct a new source, grab its token and pass that in as described above

This is what your Start method should look like:

```
cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;
Task.Delay(10000, token).ContinueWith((x) => PostGoingReport(token), token);
```

This ensures that:

1. If you cancel before delay has elapsed, delay will cancel (and continuewith task will not execute)
2. If you cancel right after delay has elapsed but before your lambda will execute, the continuewith task will not call it
3. Your `PostGoingReport` method will use the token from the source it was constructed with, and not whatever is current when it actually gets to execute

Comment: Thank you. I am now using Task.Run() with other functions aswell with the token instead of just doing await Func(). My function is wrapped in a try catch, when i press the stop button I get an exception throwing into the log. Is there a way can I make it ignore cancelled tasks as theyre not really a problem?